# How do I fix power window buttons?

Tags: ford

The power window buttons in my 2007 Ford F-150 seems to have stopped functioning for the passenger and both rear windows and sometimes my driver window stops working. Since it is happening to three out of the four windows then I figured it couldn't be the power window motors. I also figure that water got into the door where the buttons are located and damaged or gummed up the buttons. So what would be the best way to remove the paneling and troubleshoot the door or electronics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is a common problem with the 2004-08 F-150s. The good news is that if you have to replace the switches, a Ford dealer will likely have them in stock.

**Step 1:** Remove the switch panel. You should be able to stick a prying device (screwdriver, chisel, spudger, whatever) into the gap in the armrest and simply pry the entire thing up. You should see two connectors on the bottom; disconnect these. The switch housing is fitted to the armrest by some snap-tabs which should also be gently pried outward to free the switches.

**Step 2:** Remove switch covers. All you should have to do at this point is pop off the switch caps. Underneath you will see some white plastic tabs which are resting within the switch contact points. These are loose and should be easily freed, along with the contacts.

**Step 3** Check your contacts. If there is any black residue on your switches, lightly dust them off with sandpaper. If your contacts look fine, you may need to start poking around with a multimeter. If a contact is broken or otherwise unusable, you'll need to buy new switches.

Detailed photos are available at [this forum thread](http://www.f150online.com/forums/articles-how-tos/414955-how-fix-defective-window-switch.html).

Comment: Wow, awesome. I searched around the internet before and didn't find this.

Comment: Instead of sandpaper, might want to consider a eraser head instead. It's not as harsh.